# how to make html video look in the mobile

Tags: html, css

i have a video which works good in desktop but in mobile it does not looks,
i will share code here and minimal reproducible example here [see website in desktop and mobile](https://clever-curie-f9c77b.netlify.app/)

[image]

[image]

helpers can see code using f12 code inspector of chrome or mozilla
but also will post code here

i used for reference this small code reflected in `<style>` from here [take a look to this w3schools example of how to make responsive a video](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_videos.asp)

it worked for desktop but not for mobile, any solution?

html code:

```
<style>video {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }</style>


     <section class="hero">
        <section class="v-header">
            <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
                <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
                <video src="videos/2.mp4"  autoplay muted loop></video>

    
        </div>
        </section>
        <div class="heroTitulo">
            <h1>RADISOL</h1>
            <h1>El Mejor Aliado Para tu Radiador</h1>
            
        </div>

        
    </section>
```

css style here:

https://clever-curie-f9c77b.netlify.app/css/estilos.css

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't make the header absolute

```css
nav {
    padding: 10px;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    vedio {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: you welcome bro